# Effective approach to update in disconnected EF Core

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP Dotnet Core web service. This talks to a Postgres database using Entity Framework Core 1.1. When the service needs to update a database record in response to a client request there are two approaches.

Approach 1

1. Retrieve the record to be updated from the database.
2. Map the values recieved from the client onto the database entity.
3. Call SaveChanges on the database context.

Approach 2.

1. Call Update on the database context passing in the record recieved from the client. (Mapping from a DTO to database entity if required).
2. Call SaveChanges on the database context.

The two approaches behave very differently.

Approach 1

Pro. Updates just those values that have been changed from the values in the database.

Con. Takes two database round trips to perform. (Retrieve entity then update).

Approach 2.

Pro. Takes only one database round trip to perform.

Con. Updates the entire object graph passed in, even if only one value in the entities has changed.

The page in the Entity Framework Core documentation on working with disconnected entities has yet to be written.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities

We don't have a full production system in place with sufficient data to test this effectively, and at this stage of development where we are trying to resolve the parts of our application with the most risk, empirical evidence based optimisation is not sufficiently high priority for us to invest this time right now.

Given that the webserver and the database server will live within the same datacenter, what I'm looking for is a somewhat informed 'starter for 10' approach that we might take the time to optimise later, should the need arise.

The problem I have though is that these two approaches behave so totally differently but I have found no information that helps me choose between them, and without a realistically sized test system with representative throughput I suspect that the interpretation of any quick and simple local tests I could do would be largely meaningless wrt to the bandwidth and occupancy of a production scale system.

I would welcome pretty much any information or guidance.

Comment: The documentation has since been updated.

Comment: Another Con to Approach 2 I am finding is if the records does not exist EF throws an exception because it expected to update 1 row and only updated 0. Trying to find a better solution than catching the exception.

Answer (score 3):

My response is for **Approach 2**

### Synopsis

I want to **Modify only few columns** of the entity as well as **Add\Modify nested child entities**

- Here, I am updating `Scenario` entity and modifying only `ScenarioDate`.
- In its child entity, i.e. navigation property `TempScenario`, I am adding a new record
- In the nested child entity, `Scenariostation`, I am adding as well modifying the records

```
public partial class Scenario
{
    public Scenario()
    {
        InverseTempscenario = new HashSet<Scenario>();
        Scenariostation = new HashSet<Scenariostation>();
    }
    public int Scenarioid { get; set; }
    public string Scenarioname { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Scenariodate { get; set; }
    public int Streetlayerid { get; set; }
    public string Scenarionotes { get; set; }
    public int? Modifiedbyuserid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modifieddate { get; set; }
    public int? Tempscenarioid { get; set; }

    
    public virtual Scenario Tempscenario { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Scenario> InverseTempscenario { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Scenariostation> Scenariostation { get; set; }
}


public partial class Scenariostation
{
    public Scenariostation()
    {
        Scenariounit = new HashSet<Scenariounit>();
    }

    public int Scenariostationid { get; set; }
    public int Scenarioid { get; set; }
    public int Stationid { get; set; }
    public bool? Isapplicable { get; set; }
    public int? Createdbyuserid { get; set; }
    public int? Modifiedbyuserid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modifieddate { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Scenario Scenario { get; set; }
    public virtual Station Station { get; set; }
}

public partial class Station
{
    public Station()
    {
        Scenariostation = new HashSet<Scenariostation>();
    }

    public int Stationid { get; set; }
    public string Stationname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public NpgsqlPoint? Stationlocation { get; set; }
    public int? Modifiedbyuserid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modifieddate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Scenariostation> Scenariostation { get; set; }
}
```

- With EF Core, data update in a disconnected scenario is tricky if you don't want to make 2 database round trips.
- Even though 2 database trips seems not significant, it can hamper performance if the data table has millions of records.
- Also, if there are only few columns to be updated, including columns of nested child entities, `Usual Approach` will not work

#### Usual approach

```
public virtual void Update(T entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

    var returnEntity = _dbSet.Attach(entity);
    _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

But the problem here for a disconnected EF Core update, if you use this  `DbContext.Entry(entity).EntityState = EntityState.IsModified`, all the columns will updated.
and so some columns will be updated to its default value i.e. null or default data type value.

Further more, some records of `ScenarioStation` won't be updated at all because the entity state will be `UnChanged`.

So inorder to **update only the columns** which are sent from the client, somehow **EF Core needs to be told**.

### Using ChangeTracker.TrackGraph

Recently I found this `DbConetxt.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph` method which can be used to mark `Added`, `UnChanged` state for the entities.

> **difference**  is that with `TrackGraph`, you can add custom logic, as it iteratively navigates through Navigation properties of the entity.

#### My custom logic using TrackGraph

```
public virtual void UpdateThroughGraph(T entity, Dictionary<string, List<string>> columnsToBeUpdated)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

    _context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(entity, e =>
    {
        string navigationPropertyName = e.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name;

        if (e.Entry.IsKeySet)
        {
            e.Entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            e.Entry.Property("Modifieddate").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;

            if (columnsToBeUpdated.ContainsKey(navigationPropertyName))
            {
                foreach (var property in e.Entry.Properties)
                {
                    if (columnsToBeUpdated[e.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name].Contains(property.Metadata.Name))
                    {
                        property.IsModified = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.Entry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }

    });

}
```

With this approach, I am able to easily handle only required column updates as well as new additions/modifications for any of the nested child entities and its columns.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the [ASP.NET Core documentation on updating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data) useful. ASP.NET Core's examples use EF Core.

Personally I tend to go with your first approach, i.e. loading the entity, updating it and calling SaveChanges, for two reasons:

1. Approach 2 means all the data in the entity would be exposed and hidden values could be altered. That is a security risk.
2. Approach 2 is usually quicker, but if you have a lot of data in the entity then it could be slower, especially if your web connection is slow.

Most applications have more reads that writes, so I tend to focus on the queries unless testing shows that an update/create/delete is slow.

Comment: #1 in your list is not true if you only update the properties your method allows to be updated versus a generic routine that loops through all.