# EF Core fails to detect changes to disconnected object graph

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 7 and I have a *disconnected* object graph that I am struggling to figure out how to update correctly.

I have a `Casino` object which has a collection of `Jurisdiction` objects and a collection of `Bonus` objects. The `Bonus` collection never gets altered in the below examples.

I am using `_context.ChangeTracker.DebugView.ShortView` to assess whether EF is recognising the changes.
In all instances, I use

```
_context.Update(entity);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

For example:

Step 1:
If I load this `Casino`, edit it by removing two Jurisdictions and adding two different Jurisdictions, and then save, the EF change tracking is 100%:

```
Casino {Id: 7} Unchanged FK {AffiliateProgramId: 1} FK {OperatorId: 1}
Casino_Jurisdiction (Dictionary<string, object>) {CasinoId: 7, JurisdictionId: 1} Unchanged FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {JurisdictionId: 1}
Casino_Jurisdiction (Dictionary<string, object>) {CasinoId: 7, JurisdictionId: 2} Added FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {JurisdictionId: 2}
Casino_Jurisdiction (Dictionary<string, object>) {CasinoId: 7, JurisdictionId: 11} Added FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {JurisdictionId: 11}
Casino_Jurisdiction (Dictionary<string, object>) {CasinoId: 7, JurisdictionId: 13} Deleted FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {JurisdictionId: 13}
Casino_Jurisdiction (Dictionary<string, object>) {CasinoId: 7, JurisdictionId: 17} Deleted FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {JurisdictionId: 17}
BonusMatch {Id: 9} Unchanged FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {Id: 9}
BonusMatch {Id: 870} Unchanged FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {Id: 870}
```

Step 2: if I load the same `Casino`, then map it to a DTO object (as if it were being sent to the UI), then make the above change, then map it back to a domain object (using ValueInjecter) and save, I get the following:

```
Casino {Id: 7} Modified FK {AffiliateProgramId: 1} FK {OperatorId: 1}
Casino_Jurisdiction (Dictionary<string, object>) {CasinoId: 7, JurisdictionId: 1} Unchanged FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {JurisdictionId: 1}
Casino_Jurisdiction (Dictionary<string, object>) {CasinoId: 7, JurisdictionId: 13} Unchanged FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {JurisdictionId: 13}
Casino_Jurisdiction (Dictionary<string, object>) {CasinoId: 7, JurisdictionId: 17} Unchanged FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {JurisdictionId: 17}
BonusMatch {Id: 9} Unchanged FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {Id: 9}
BonusMatch {Id: 870} Unchanged FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {Id: 870
```

So EF is not handling it correctly as a result

Step 3: same as Step 2, but I call [Attach(entity)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-7.0) The `DebugView` shows:

```
Casino {Id: 7} Unchanged FK {AffiliateProgramId: 1} FK {OperatorId: 1}
Casino_Jurisdiction (Dictionary<string, object>) {CasinoId: 7, JurisdictionId: 1} Unchanged FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {JurisdictionId: 1}
Casino_Jurisdiction (Dictionary<string, object>) {CasinoId: 7, JurisdictionId: 2} Unchanged FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {JurisdictionId: 2}
Casino_Jurisdiction (Dictionary<string, object>) {CasinoId: 7, JurisdictionId: 11} Unchanged FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {JurisdictionId: 11}
```

Which is the same as Step 2, BUT the other child collections have incorrect tracking info:

```
Bonus {Id: -2147482647} Added FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {Id: -2147482647}
Bonus {Id: -2147482646} Added FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {Id: -2147482646}
```

EF then generates SQL to INSERT these, which does not reflect the actual change.

If I call `_context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` before saving the entity in STEP 2, I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Jurisdiction' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'
```

I have tried using the [TrackGraph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-7.0) instead of `Attach()` :

```
_context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(entity, e =>
{
    if (e.Entry.IsKeySet)
    {
        try
        {
            e.Entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)    // There were instances where two child collections had children that existed in both collections, so EF threw an exception likethe one above
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.Entry.State = EntityState.Added;
    }
});
```

but, I get the same as Step 3:

```
Casino_Jurisdiction (Dictionary<string, object>) {CasinoId: 7, JurisdictionId: 1} Unchanged FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {JurisdictionId: 1}
Casino_Jurisdiction (Dictionary<string, object>) {CasinoId: 7, JurisdictionId: 2} Unchanged FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {JurisdictionId: 2}
Casino_Jurisdiction (Dictionary<string, object>) {CasinoId: 7, JurisdictionId: 11} Unchanged FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {JurisdictionId: 11}
Bonus {Id: -2147482647} Added FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {Id: -2147482647}
Bonus {Id: -2147482646} Added FK {CasinoId: 7} FK {Id: -2147482646}
```

So... How does one attach an object graph in such a way that EF can compare and figure out what actually changed? Or is this something I need to iterate over and actually inform EF? The documentation suggests you just "attach" and done

It is clear from Step 1, that my relationships are configured correctly:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Casino>()
        .HasMany(a => a.Jurisdictions)
        .WithMany(b => b.Casinos)
        .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
            "Casino_Jurisdiction",
            j => j
                .HasOne<Jurisdiction>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("JurisdictionId")
                ,
            j => j
                .HasOne<Casino>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("CasinoId")
        );
```

You can see more of the code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30393)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which shows the problem you have by simulating the steps you are doing (or the UI and server). Keep in mind that the ChangeTracker of entity framework has to actually *see* the changes being made. It can't guess what happened outside of the context and react accordingly with the given "end result" entity.

Comment: @Progman I can't really. Like I said, I load the entity and then use nested constructors to map to and from a DTO object. Including all the code necessary to reproduce it would be impractical. The domain and DTO objects are essentially 1:1 copies of each other. The issue is tracking these changes that happen outside of EF's visibility

If EF doesn't "see" the changes, then how is any web app supposed to use it? The changes will happen client-side where EF obviously has no visibility

Comment: You can read the entities from the context and update them based on the received DTO. Check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61675903/ef-6-update-entity-from-dto-but-only-existing-properties-generic-code, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66246953/edit-update-collections-in-ef-core-from-dto-or-repository or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415288/effective-approach-to-update-in-disconnected-ef-core

Answer (score 1):

I am struggling with the same issue. I got it working as expected with that:

First try to load the current values from database in "existingParentEntity" while having a object from the client (clientParentEntity):

```
var existingParentEntity = await db.ParentEntity
    .Where(e => e.Id == clientParentEntity.Id)
    .Include(e => e.ChildEntity)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Validate it and if valid, Attach it and its child(ren) to the context to start tracking changes:

```
// Start change tracking
db.ParentEntity.Attach(existingParentEntity);
// Also for the child
if (existingParentEntity.ChildEntity != null)
    db.ChildEntity.Attach(existingParentEntity.ChildEntity);

// Apply changes from client-object
db.Entry(existingParentEntity)
    .CurrentValues
    .SetValues(clientParentEntity);
// Also for the child
if (clientParentEntity.ChildEntity != null)
    db.Entry(existingParentEntity.ChildEntity)
        .CurrentValues
        .SetValues(clientParentEntity.ChildEntity);
```

In your example you have a list of children, so you would need to iterate over them.

For now this works better for me than the TrackGraph. Maybe i did not get it, but if anyone else has a better idea, go for it.

Maybe check this thread when you want to use the TrackGraph, but it has no final answer either: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415288/effective-approach-to-update-in-disconnected-ef-core)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have actually just been playing around with the `.CurrentValues.SetValues` approach but without any luck. I also ended up trying to iterate over the collection, as you suggested, but  `db.Entry(existingParentEntity.ChildEntity)` causes ChildEntity to be updated. That seems to be what you want, but in my case the collection (jurisdictions) is a many-to-many relationship and I don't want to the Jurisdiction record to be updated - only the intersect table.

Comment: oh - I updated my question with a link to a revised version of this question that I posted on the EFCore git repo